# nginx emerg error with type_hash

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve a single app with nginx, but whenever I start it, I get the following error (and warning):

```
nginx: [warn] duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /var/www/nginx.conf:33
nginx: [emerg] could not build the types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
```

From what I've gathered, this `emerg` error is common when people have multiple servers running on the same box, but this is the only nginx instance that I have running.

Here is my config file:

```
user root;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    # Enumerate all the Tornado servers here
    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:4000;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css text/xml
               application/x-javascript application/xml
               application/atom+xml text/javascript;

    # Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout
    # on the Tornado server (to avoid propagating "queries of death"
    # to all frontends)
    proxy_next_upstream error;

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Allow file uploads
        client_max_body_size 50M;

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

---

I had tried adding the line

```
types_hash_max_size 2048;
```

But I was getting an error along the lines of *"you can't put that there."* After doing some digging, I discovered that I needed to put this into the `html` section of the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the type `text/html` from the `gzip_types` string.`text/html` is always gzip compressed, and you don't need to specify it separately.